# ELK - Format SIEM alerts

Tags: kibana, alert, elastic-stack, elk

I'm using ELK v7.12.1. I have enabled few SIEM rules and configured an email action. I'm able to access the event details through `{{#context.alerts}} {{.}}{{/context.alerts}}`.

But when sending the mail the content is coming in one line. Is there any way to format the SIEM alert using HTML tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `"{{#context.alerts}} {{.}}{{/context.alerts}}"`
you can separate each field by using the following format
(depend on your field names):

```
{{/context.alerts}}
Account ID:{{accountId}}
{{/context.alerts}}
```

(the `{{.}}` moustache trows all the fields)

Example including HTML:

```html
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SIEM ALERT</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


<p>{{/context.alerts}}
Account ID:{{accountId}}
{{/context.alerts}}</p>

</body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).